# When configuring multi-threaded execution for unit tests, the coverage data reported by Cobertura is incorrect

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, cobertura

In maven project, when configuring multi-threaded execution for unit tests, the coverage data reported by Cobertura is incorrect. Moreover, the results vary with each execution。

My configuration is as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
    <configuration>
        <forkCount>1C</forkCount>
        <reuseForks>true</reuseForks>
        <parallel>classesAndMethods</parallel>
        <threadCount>4</threadCount>
        <trimStackTrace>true</trimStackTrace>
        <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/cobertura</outputDirectory>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        <check>
        </check>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The issue occurs in my actual business project. However, it cannot be reproduced in a simpler example project.

As mentioned above. After I removed the configuration lines in the maven-surefire-plugin, the coverage data reported by Cobertura is correct, and, the results of multiple executions are the same.

Comment: In Gradle, each fork would write to a separate coverage file. You could then combine the coverage files into a single file after all tests finished before running the coverage report (no synchronization of coverage files required). I'm not sure how you'd do this with maven.

Comment: First coberatura is outdated.. second why not using JaCoCo and also why using old plugin version (surefire-plugin: ? Which JDK, Maven version do you run?

Comment: Why not JaCoCo? In a multi-module scenario, aggregating coverage reports requires adding an additional module, which I don't want to do. JDK1.8 , Maven 3.5.0

Comment: After conducting some tests, it was found that the issue was actually caused by the configuration forkCount=1C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally，I figured out this question myself.Hope it can help someone else.
https://github.com/cobertura/cobertura/issues/434
I just remove those lines and deploy a new version into my own repository, and it works for me.